# How to compile a minimalistic library of cpp protocol-buffers for iphone?

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, xcode, protocol-buffers

## Goal:

I am looking for a way to implement protocol buffers (by google) into an iphone-app using xcode as my IDE. 
https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/

## Background:

Only C++, Java, Python are supported by google directly.

Development for a third party project in ObjC seems to be stopped a few years ago.
https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-objc/

When searching for protocol-buffers and iphone I usually find two references to two third-party projects in C#:

one by Marc Gravell: https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/

and one by Jonathan Skeet: https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/

(I am not sure if or how they are to be used with xcode and posted a question on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25524852/can-i-use-protobuf-net-or-protobuf-csharp-port-with-xcode)

## Situation:

One other interesting approach for iphone dev by Bennett Smith is „simply“ using the Google c++ source  https://gist.github.com/BennettSmith/7150245). 
The (btw awesome!) script works very nicely and produces a two libraries: a regular and a lite one.

What makes me curious is the size of those libraries (.a files). Including all builds (x86_64_mac, i386_ios_sim, armv7,armv7s,arm64) the size of the regular library is close to 89 MB and the size of the life-library is still larger than 8 MB.

## Questions:

1.) Why are the files that large? To my knowledge lite libraries for android implementation of protobuf are closer to 100 KB and the library for iphone by Marc Gravell (see above) is also closer to 100 KB.

I tried to reduce the size by not including the x86_64_mac and i386_ios_sim (setting the provided for controls in the script to 0) but the script ends with an error not leaving any files.
(When only eliminating the i386_ios_sim it seems to work but reduces size to 6-7 MB only.)
2.) Does anyone know how to configure the script to include only the iphone-builds?

3.) How could I further reduce the size of such C++ library as much as possible (or at least as reasonable)? Has anyone suggestions on how to strip the google cpp files to a „minimalistic“ build and compile a library? So far I found only a link that suggested to drop the compiler and the unittest files. (http://rxwen.blogspot.de/2011/11/use-protobuf-on-iphone-app.html) but unfortunately I've not yet seen any discussion on the relevance of other files.

4.) (Bonus:) When using this C++ library I will have to use a wrapper object. While I’ve found general articles on this on the net, is anyone aware of a solution for protobufs I could have a look at?

Answer (score 1):

Why not give it a try 
https://github.com/booyah/protobuf-objc
or any of forks https://github.com/booyah/protobuf-objc/network

Comment: Thank you very much - I will certainly have a look at it.